# Can you convert a color topic from a bag file to monochrome?

Tags: ros, ethzasl-ptam, bagfiles

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am using the ethzasl_ptam package. It requires monochrome images. I want to use RGB-D bag files. The images come in on the /camera/rgb/image_color topic.

Is there a way convert a color topic from a bag file to monochrome ?

Or do I have to convert the bag file to images and then convert the color images to monochrome ?

And if so, how do I then use the images with ethzasl_ptam ?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248229/can-you-convert-a-color-topic-from-a-bag-file-to-monochrome-?/) by [ap](https://answers.ros.org/users/3948/ap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2016-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use an `image_proc` node http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc, have it subscribe to your image_color and then you will get an image_mono output.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ap](https://answers.ros.org/users/3948/ap/) on 2016-11-24**:
Thanks for the reply. Had a look at image_proc. Looks like it subscribes to the image_raw topic. Is there a way I can make it subscribe to  "/camera/rgb/image_color" instead ? I don't have the image_raw topic in the bag file. Thanks

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-11-25**:
`rosrun image_proc image_proc image_raw:=/camera/rgb/image_color __ns:=/camera/rgb/converted` -> remap the image_raw topic to your topic, and put the namespace where image_proc won't conflict with other topics http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments